# Cant align longtable cell to the top

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable

I am making a long table and the text in columns is starting in the middle or is flushed to the bottom.

[image: wrong longtable]

```
    %
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,fleqn]{article} 
%\documentclass[natbib,fleqn,smallextended]{svjour3}
%
\usepackage{filecontents}
%
%Author list
\usepackage[noblocks,auth-lg]{authblk}
%
%
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % for upright CO2
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
%\usepackage{tabularx}%modifiable tabular
%\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{longtable}
%
%setting spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
%\singlespacing
%\onehalfspacing
%For other sizes use the \setstretch command like this:
%\setstretch{1.8}
\usepackage[square,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}
%line Numbers
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers*[1]
%to set numbering format
\usepackage{enumerate}
%Maths
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%for deg
\usepackage{gensymb}
%for permil
\usepackage{wasysym}
% Headers and Footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\lhead{Bose et al}
%\rhead{Past p\ce{CO_2} of air from Tree-ring cellulose $\delta^{13}C$}
% for rotating floats
\usepackage{lscape}
%for subfigures and tables
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subfig}
%automatic referencing
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
%for long tables
\usepackage{longtable}
%made commands
\newcommand{\mytilde}{\raise.17ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mathtt{\sim}$}} %around tilde

\title{saf}
%
%\author{}
\author{}
%\author{}
%\author{}
%\affil{}
%\author{}
%\affil{}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\subsubsection*{Keywords}

\section*{Introduction}

Long term changes 
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'

\begin{longtable}{lp{5cm}p{4.5cm}p{4.5cm}@{}}
            & \textbf{dsf} & \textbf{sdafg} & \textbf{hj} \\
%          &  &  &  \\
    A     &  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{test} ifiuyruldlulud & U-Pb, K-Ar, etc. & Mg/Ca, Sr/Ca, etc. \\
%          &  &  &  \\
      \caption{ohgg'pghepgn  ;dlng;ng zxnv/.sadng/;erw}
  \label{tabmethods}%
\end{longtable}%

\clearpage
% Tables and Figures

\end{document}
```

no clues why this isnt working

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE!  The output looks normal to me.  Everything is aligned on its baseline.   Including the graphic, which has the baseline along the bottom edge by default.  If you want to adjust the baseline of the graphic, then [`graphbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphbox?lang=en) can help.

Comment: I want to align this to the top instead of the baseline :(

Comment: So try adding `\usepackage{graphbox}` and then add an `align=t` option to your  `\includegraphics`. 
 Like so`\includegraphics[align=t]{whatever.png}` ?

Comment: This did solve the problem! please write this as an answer so that I can mark it as the solution. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested...
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\begin{document}

With \verb|\includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image-a}|

\smallskip

\begin{tabular}{lll}
    A & B & C\\
    Another & \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image-a} & over here \\
    Finally & a longer line to show & the alignment
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
With \verb|\includegraphics[align=t,width=1in]{example-image-a}|

\smallskip

\begin{tabular}{lll}
    A & B & C\\
    Another & \includegraphics[align=t,width=1in]{example-image-a} & over here \\
    Finally & a longer line to show & the alignment
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
With \verb|\includegraphics[align=c,width=1in]{example-image-a}|

\smallskip

\begin{tabular}{lll}
    A & B & C\\
    Another & \includegraphics[align=c,width=1in]{example-image-a} & over here \\
    Finally & a longer line to show & the alignment
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```